# How much better is Thunderbolt external HDD for video editing?

Tags: mp4, windows, usb, laptop, thunderbolt

For the two activities of

1. transferring 10GB-large mp4 (`.mts`) video files from external HDD
   to laptop, and
2. editing these same files directly on the connected external HDD drive,

how much better/faster do these activities become using a **Thunderbolt connection** instead of a **USB connection** on a Windows 11 laptop?

Comment: HDDs are a bit slow for video, no matter how they're connected.

Comment: Aren't HDDs best for video storage, while SSD is best for video editing?

Comment: HDDs last longer, unpowered, sitting on a shelf. For everything else you want speed.

Comment: Heard HDDs only have a (recommended) life of 5 years

Comment: Whereas unpowered SSDs are only a year. You've still a lot of research to do.

Comment: I just drew out the confirmatory reaction I was looking for. thank u.